# Sum and count data from columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a `DataFrame` like:

```
1        member_id  application_name  active_seconds 
2           192180             Opera   6
3           192180             Opera   7
4           192180             Chrome  243
5           5433112            Chrome   52
6           5433112            Opera   34
7           5433112            Chrome 465
```

And I try to group it.

I want to count `application_name` to id and sum `active_seconds` to `application_name`.
I use `df.groupby(['member_id', 'application_name'])['event_duration'].sum()` and `df.groupby(['member_id', 'application_name']).size()` and second return to me correct value, but first return

```
       member_id  application_name  active_seconds
       192180             Opera             67
       192180             Chrome            243
       5433112            Chrome           52465
       5433112            Opera              34
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your `active_seconds` seem to be of `dtype` `string`, so `sum()` concatenates them.

If you do `df.info()`, `active_seconds` probably shows `object` as `dtype`, which implies they are `string` rather than `int`. Do

```
df.active_seconds =  pd.to_numeric(df.active_seconds)
```

to convert. In case there are errors, you can use the keyword `errors` to handle those as explained in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html).

Comment: `ValueError: Unable to parse string`

Comment: Take a look at all the data in `active_seconds` - there must be some that can't be converted to numbers. The error message indicates that the `dtype` is indeed `string`, though.

Comment: Why some can't convert to numbers?

Comment: Because some don't fit the number format. They're actual strings (like with letters), or 'Nan' as string, or numbers formatted like '1.234,45' or anything of that nature.

Comment: How can I sum that, if I can't convert it? This data too much, there are 4 million strings

Comment: See to_numeric docs - you can handle the errors so they become NaN or remain strings using eg error='coerce'. You can then see how many cases there are, and get a list of numbers you can sum. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html